# Which algorithm for forecasting a binary time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

I would like to write the code to forecast the status. The status 0 means non-active, 1 means active. I would like to predict the future month (e.g 2016/6/1), the status should be "0" or "1".

What algorithm could be used in such a situation?

`date       status
2016/1/10   0
2016/1/19   0
2016/2/2    1
2016/2/10   1
2016/3/1    0
2016/4/2    1
2016/4/3    0
2016/5/4    0
2016/5/5    1`

Comment: Do you have any other variables/predictors?

Answer (score 0):

It'll mostly depend on the features you have, however having only one feature (i.e. a date) will be insufficient for most models. Check [RNN](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) as the retain some "memory" of previous feature values, and that may serve to turn the single feature into multiple ones.